# Dropdown Menu Somehow Not Working

Tags: html, css

I have went through W3Schools to attempt understanding the coding structure of dropdown menus. When opening the page and hovering your cursor to the 'Merch' text it is supposed to display the dropdown menu. For some reason, however, it is not showing. Please amplify for me and show me where I went wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: dimgray;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

#dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: darkgray;
  min-width: 140px;
}

#dropdown a {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

#dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

#dropbtn:hover #dropdown {
  display: block;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="dropbtn">Merch</a>
        <div id="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Shirts</a>
          <a href="#">Pants</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this change in CSS

```
#dropbtn:hover + #dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

Dropdown is not a child, it is next element in your current html setup, so, this [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) will find it.

Or, **better**, place id on *li element* (parent):

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li id="dropbtn"><a href="#" >Merch</a>
        <div id="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Shirts</a>
          <a href="#">Pants</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>


#dropbtn:hover  #dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3bfgzf37/

If you use first solution, dropdown dissapears fast, and behave strange... 
Explanation: hover on *a* is *not* hover on dropdown (a is sibling), hover on li element, is, in the same time, hover on dropdown (parent-child, dropdown is 'inside' li - that produces consistent, desired, behavior).

Second one is better.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: dimgray;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

#dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
  background-color: darkgray;
  min-width: 140px;
}

#dropdown a {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

#dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

#dropbtn:hover  #dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li id="dropbtn"><a href="#" >Merch</a>
        <div id="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Shirts</a>
          <a href="#">Pants</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I had not realize that the ID was entered in the a element.

Answer (score 0):

Your style tag should be outside the head tag. Plus, the dropdown in this code works now. Just do some slight changes to the colors to your desire. :)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
ul {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: dimgray;
  list-style-type: none;
}    
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
}
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown     content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: gray;
}
</style>
<body>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Merch</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Shirts</a>
          <a href="#">Pants</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```